# Interact with files in a folder using client side JavaScript [React]

Tags: javascript

I would like to build a small client-side javascript application (No node js involved, only browser javascript) that can access a list of files in a directory on my computer, fetch the content of a particular file in a javascript variable and also modify the content of a file in the directory by setting it to the value of a javascript variable.

I want to use React for my application but I think the question is not specific to React but involves client-side JavaScript in general.

Is this doable?

What tools (libraries, classes...) do I need to use for this purpose?

Thanks in advance for your answer.

Comment: I do not believe this will be possible in a client-side browser-only web app.  But perhaps somebody can show me to be incorrect.

Comment: It wasn't possible for a long time to get access to a user's filesystem via a web browser because of security reasons, but there is an experimental technology, check this out: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/File_System_Access_API.

Comment: @CommercialSuicide it says "This interface will not grant you access to the users filesystem. Instead you will have a "virtual drive" within the browser sandbox. If you want to gain access to the users filesystem you need to invoke the user by eg. installing a Chrome extension. The relevant Chrome API can be found here." How should I interpret that?

Comment: @Platus, I used the wrong link, updated my previous comment.

Comment: Ok, @CommercialSuicide can I get the list of file names in a specific directory with this API?